# Power BI Filter - How to filter dataset without measures?

Tags: powerbi

Need to have 2 slicers one for date (end date) and the other number of weeks (Now). This two slicers will be used to generate another date (start date) through a calculation (end date - Now). The start date and end date is then used to filter a dataset.

I have attempted this using  measures but since a measure cannot be used in calculate table or summarise it fails to give me what I need.

[image: This image shows my attempt]

Any other ideas and approaches to this problem?

Comment: Please share what you tried so far. This isn't a puzzle, where people trying to help you have to find all the required pieces first!

Comment: Ive added screen shots of my attempt. the issue with that approach is that calculatetable and summarize require column for filters rather than measures

Comment: You  can use measures to filter data. Just save them into variables.

Comment: ive tried that but it didnt work for some reason, it was showing a range of values rather than those specific values